# How to atomically update different databases?

Tags: amazon-rds, transaction

I have a lambda function which receives data of newly signed up users from a message queue and insert that same data in two different databases.

Those two databases belong to two different microservices. First - users service which is using RDS postgres, and second - admin service whose database is basically a single DynamoDB table.

**I want to achieve "all or nothing" behavior for data insertions in the two databases - either insertion in both databases succeeds or insertions don't happen in either of them.**

- How can I have an "atomic transaction" for inserting in the two databases, achieving "all or nothing" behavior?
- What if data gets inserted in admin service's DynamoDB table but fail to get inserted in users service's postgres table for some reason - how can I "rollback" the insertion in DyanamoDB?

I may achieve this kind of functionality at code level but the code would be pretty messed up if let's say I have "all or nothing" insertions in 5 instead of 2 different databases.

I wonder if there is some standard way to have an atomic transaction like behavior when it comes to interacting with different DBs altogether.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I wonder if there is some standard way to have an atomic transaction like behavior when it comes to interacting with different DBs altogether.

Yes, it's called [distributed transactions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributed_transaction). It requires an extra component, a transaction coordinator, that implements a two-phase commit protocol. If you don't want to implement it in your code, you'll need to set up one of the existing 3d party implementations.